# Pre-processing an array for pretty display using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do I use PHP to process and store the array below in a string called $answer so that when I echo $answer I get the formatted HTML. I get that I can just loop through the array in the front-end to show each result but in this instance I want to avoid doing this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [assetname] => My file 1
                [asseturl] => http://URL of file 1
            )

        [1] => Array
        (
                [assetname] => My file 2
                [asseturl] => http://URL of file 2
        )
```

Above array data to be processed so that when I echo $answer, I get the following:

```
<p>Here is a list of results:</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://URL of file 1">My file 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://URL of file 2">My file 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to do this task?

Comment: I've tried using implode to basically flatten the array and whilst that works for simple arrays, I haven't been able to extend it to work for my example.

Comment: How about you try to iterate over each subarray and try to create the required pattern. Using each subarray you could generate "<li><a href="assetURL">assetName</a></li>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple. Just write a function taking your answers array. And then instead of printing it directly, you concatenate a string and return that string.

```
function answer_list(array $answers) : string
{
    $list = "<ul>";
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $list .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', 
            urlencode($answer['asseturl']),
            htmlspecialchars($answer['assetname'])
        );
    }
    $list .= "</ul>";
    return $list;
}
```

I prefer to use ext/DOM for this thoigh, because that will encode any special chars for you automatically and can return a formatted string, e.g.

```
function answer_list(array $answers) : string
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $li = $dom->createElement('li');
        $a = $dom->createElement('a', $answer['assetname']);
        $a->setAttribute('href', $answer['asseturl']);
        $li->appendChild($a);
        $ul->appendChild($li);
    }
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    return $dom->saveHTML($ul);
}
```

Comment: Wont be much nicer if you let the OP try himself.

Comment: Thanks. Whilst I knew how to iterate through an array, I thought that would just result in another array which is not what I wanted. I now know you can iterate through an array to become a string in this way.